# Setting Value of a cftextarea field

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I have been working all day to update a cfTextArea control using jQuery, to no avail.  All I want to do is change the value of the textarea when a user clicks a link.  I've simplified it down to the code below.

Please note, cfTextarea generates its own ID values, which necessitates getting the id manually.

Personally, I would throw cfTextarea out the door, but it's legacy code and I have to keep it for now.

```
<script>

            $(function(){

                $('#link').bind('click',function(){

                    var id = document.forms[0].mytextarea.id;   
                    $('#' + id).html('<span>This is my new HTML</span>');

                });

            });

        </script>

        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="link">Fill Text Area</a>

        <cfform>

            <cftextarea     name        = "mytextarea"
                            enabled     = "yes"
                            richText    = "yes" 
                            width       = "470" 
                            toolbar     = "Basic"></cftextarea>
        </cfform>
```

Comment: Have you considered using a non-`<cfform>` rich text editor? Basically the extjs powered `<cftextarea>` is fighting jQuery.

Comment: Would love to but as mentioned, I'm stuck for now with legacy code.

Comment: Matt, not sure what you mean.  If I set the new HTML as exampled above, and then write it to the console, I'm getting exactly what I'm putting in.

Comment: Yes, the ID is unique (It's the only control on the page).  I tried hard coding my own id attribute but it's overwritten with Coldfusion's own.

Comment: Heading home for the day.  Will pick this up in the morning.

Comment: What's the purpose of the link?  Why not populate the textarea when the page loads?

Comment: Better you try using **$('#' + id).val()** instead of **$('#' + id).html()**

Comment: Dan, business requirements indicate the population of this textarea according to what the end user clicks.  In this case, they click the link and the textarea populates with pre-canned HTML.

Comment: Rajash, I've tried val(), html(), text() and nothing works.  If I remove the richtext="yes" attribute, all is well.  When I put it back in, no dice.

Comment: Leigh, thank you!  This is the answer.  I had to chuckle at your "brief search" comment though!  I did more than a brief search and ended up flat.  Just didn't use the right terms I guesss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have a lot of experience with `cftextearea`, but a brief search suggests you can grab the underlying editor with [ColdFusion.RichText.getEditorObject](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ColdFusion.RichText.getEditorObject) and use the editor's `SetData` or `SetHTML` (deprecated) method to change the value. In CF9+

```
var editor = ColdFusion.RichText.getEditorObject("mytextarea");
editor.SetData('<span>This is my new HTML</span>');
```

As an aside, if you are *really* stuck with the built in ajax stuff, you might want to use [AjaxOnLoad](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-79e1.html), rather than jQuery, just to ensure everything aligns properly.